# Using MacPorts bash, tab completion no longer lists hidden / dot files

Tags: terminal, bash, macports

I used MacPorts to install bash (bash @4.3.8_0). I switched Terminal to use `/opt/local/bin/bash` as the command to startup.

However, now when I type `vim ~/.<tab><tab>`, it no longer lists dot files. If I switch back to using the default Mac OS X shell command, it works by listing the hidden dot files.

Does anyone know what settings I need to switch?

I've tried adding `set match-hidden-files on` in my `~/.inputrc` as well as running `shopt -s dotglob` but neither seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue filed for this in [MacPorts Trac](http://trac.macports.org/ticket/43265). The real issue is that auto completion does not work for any paths starting with ~ (tilde) — try `vim .<tab><tab>`.